# MySQL merge data from two table using different conditions and sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, database, e-commerce

I have two tables, country and country_description. Both tables contains store_id and country_id.

**country** :

```
country_row_id,
country_id,
store_id,
status,
date_added,
is_delete
```

**country_description** :

```
country_id,
store_id,
language_id,
name,
description
```

These tables contains default values with store_id = 0 which means By default all the stores will see the results from store_id = 0 but when they try to insert any new country or edit any existing default country than it will be only added or updated for that particular store only and the changes for that store only visible to that store related queries only.

For Example, Sample Data

```
country table
county_row_id  country_id store_id  status  date_added  is_delete
       1           1          0        1    06/06/2015      0  
       2           2          0        1    06/06/2015      0
       3           3          0        1    06/06/2015      0
       4           4          0        1    06/06/2015      0
       5           3          5        1    07/07/2015      0
       6           1          5        0    07/07/2015      0
       7           4          5        1    07/07/2015      1  

country_description table
country_id  store_id language_id  name    description
      1         0         0       USA     United States of America
      2         0         0       Russia  Russia
      3         0         0       UK      United Kingdom
      4         0         0       India   Bharat
      3         5         0       England United Kingdom
      1         5         0       US      United States of America
      4         5         0       Bharat  India
```

Now we would like to get list of Countries for store_id = 5 which will be all defaults with store_id = 0 plus overwrite the values added or updated for store_id =5.

```
getCountries() : List of Countries in Ascending Order of their Name

SELECT *
FROM country c LEFT JOIN country_description cd
ON (c.country_id = cd.country_id AND c.store_id = cd.store_id)
WHERE (c.store_id = 0 OR c.store_id = 5) AND c.status = 1 AND c.is_delete = 0
ORDER BY cd.name ASC GROUP BY c.store_id
```

With above query we are getting the results but it still not showing in ascending order by the name. We have fixed this issue by selecting sub_queries by ordering first and then group by.

Now we need to restrict the results like, if any country is set 1 to is_delete for particular store than the result should not get that row in result although it has value with default store_id 0. We have tried using LEFT JOIN and UNION but it doesn't solving our concern in single query so anyone has any idea or logic to work it out with optimized way.

My Expected Output for Store ID 5 with Default Values of Store ID 0 :

```
country_id  store_id  name      status
     3          5     England      0
     1          5     US           1
     2          0     Russia       1

Note : Not showing country_id 4 as it has set is_delete = 1.
```

I have tried to find out solution but did not found which can solve my concern so trying post the question to get some help.

Comment: Could you please add your expected output?

Comment: Added the expected result set.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to jive with the data you gave.  Based on what I see, `USA`, not `US`, should appear in the output.

Comment: Default value is USA with store id = 0 but as its updated for store id = 5 with US so for that store we need its updated value as US.

Comment: Why are you Grouping, I mean, what's the reason of that Group By there?

Comment: To get the unique values of county by store_id. (If store_id 5 available than it and not available then default value with store_id 0)